# <br> not collapsing with visibility:collapse

Tags: javascript, html

For some strange reason, `visibility:collapse` does not collapse the `<br>` (new line) element

I want to use visibility instead of display. I realize that there are a lot of options for visibility, and there could be an alternative. How can I achieve this?

```html
a<span style=visibility:collapse><br>invisible text<br><br></span>a
<br><br>
b<span style=display:none><br>invisible text<br><br></span>b
```

Comment: So, `visibility: collapse` [behaves the same](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility#values) as `visibility:hidden` for non-table and non-flex box elements.  The element is hidden but the space it occupies is still there.  That really has no effect for `br`.  What is your intent, something more like `display: none`?

Comment: For questions like this, it's often quicker to go to MDN and look up the CSS property. It's well-documented there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "collapse" mode works just like "hidden" most of the time. The content is not shown (your "invisible text") but the element still affects the layout as if it were.

That mode is most useful for table rows and flex items.